# Prevent user from attaching to run-by-developer instance of MS-Office process

Tags: c#, c++, vba, com, ms-office

I encounter the following issue:
After I start any Ms-Office application via COM in my C++ code (Word, Excel, PowerPoint, Visio) and make it hidden - then if user starts its own intance of that application - it will attach to run-by-my-code office process, while I have no idea of that. Eventually after my code has executed I close Office Application and a user will lose its work (As far as they attached to my process and didn't start its own one)

So,

1) is there any way to prevent a user from attaching to my instance of Office Application and start its own process? Maybe a parameter for CoCreateInstance, or something else?

2) Or (Another option) - how to detect that user has just attached to run-by-me office process ?

Will appreciate any help.

Here is a piece of code on how I create Office Application

```
CComPtr<IDispatch> pOffApp;
hr = pOfficeApp.CoCreateInstance(L"Word.Application", NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER); //may also be "Excel.Application", "Visio.Application" etc.
```

Answer (score 3):

There used to be a good KB article on this, but it's disappeared... The essence was posted in an answer on the MSDN forums, by Bessie Zhao, which I copy here, with what I can remember from the KB explanation below it:

> Have you tried the Workaround of KB 188546:
>   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/188546/EN-US/? It introduces a way as
>   below. Before you create your Word object, first create a temporary
>   Word object. After you create your object, close the temporary object.
>   This causes Word to act properly when you control it through
>   Automation (that is, if a user interactively starts Word, a new
>   instance of Word is opened for the user). The automation instance
>   remains hidden and separate. Code like this,
>
> ```
>         object missing = Type.Missing;
>         Word.Application temp = new Word.Application();
>         Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
>         wordApp.Visible = true;
>         temp.Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
>         temp = null;
>         ...
> ```

The reason for this is how Office applications use the ROT (Running Object Table). Only *one* instance of an Office application will ever be present in the ROT - the first one started.

If some other application than Office creates an instance of that application, then that's the one in the ROT. Office is designed to look for a running instance in the ROT and, if one is present, use that when the user starts the application or opens a document. Which is why the situation described in the question is possible.

The work-around basically says: create two instances. Use the second, which won't be in the ROT, then destroy the first. At this point, no instance of the Office application is in the ROT, so when the user invokes it, not finding anything in the ROT, the Office application creates a new instance of itself, independent of that used by the software.

Comment: That is important asnwer and is close to my case. Since I work in a multithreaded environment - I may launch up to 4, 8 or more Office Application instances (depending on processor cores count) - so it would be great to avoid another Office App launch per each "actual working" Office instance.  But your answer led me to the other possible solution : launch 1 MS Office instance and remove it from ROT - so that user will start its own application instance. If you have any ideas on how to do this, or other thoughts on this matter - will appreciate!

Comment: @JohnBosco Actually, my answer is essentially that, although it appears not to have been clear enough. I believe it's necessary to keep that second instance, that's not in the ROT, open, however.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I was clear enough :) 
What I mean is the solution where only 1 instance of Word is launched: 1) start an instance of Word 2) Somehow remove its entry from the ROT without starting another Word instance (e.g. via `IRunningObjectTable::Revoke` or some other way).
What do you think about that?

Comment: Is that possible? You'd have to try it - I've never tried to manipulate the ROT directly...

Comment: well, it would be great if I could. 
Thank you for your replies!

Answer (score 0):

Get the `Application` Object. Check the `Application.Visible` property. If the application is visible than you should not exit the application.

Comment: Great, 
but this approach has pitfalls: ms-office may become visible after you set `Application.Visible` to `false` : e.g. when you open a document with a password application becomes visible, and I suspect that this may not be the only case when it suddenly turns visible.

Comment: Yes but if it becomes visible, after you set it to false, you can check it when you want to exit, check the Visible property before you exit... This is what I mean.

Comment: Yeah, I understood, but I suspect that there may be some other reasons why MS Office may become Visible without user interference - like in the case when it shows "enter password" modal dialog . 
Thus, when I want to shutdown MS Office, I check  `Visible` property, it turns to be `true` - and I don't know whether it is visible because user has started new instance or because of other reasons . 
What I mean is that application visibility may not be a satisfactory condition when determining whether user has started new office process :(

Comment: And why do you want to exit the application? If it's gone Visible for any reason, you are no longer in charge...

Comment: well, as long as my code is executed in a multithreaded environment - I may launch up to 4, 8 or more Office Application instances (depending on processor cores count). So if I don't quit the application when I should - unclosed applications may overwhelm a system.