# How to force a fresh and independent instance of Word

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

Whatever way one opens Word (Excel etc.) I aim that the instance is 'safe' and independent. What I mean by that is that if the user currently has a Word window open that this doesn't interact with what my software is opening and that both windows can operate independent of one another.

The best way to describe this is the effect of right-clicking on Word or Excel in the taskbar and opening up a new Word (or Excel) window (as opposed to opening a file). Each time you do this, you seem to get a complete and independent instance.

It would seem that  the following code:

```
        Dim wdApp As Word.Application
        Dim oDoc As Word.Document
        wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
```

... will open up within an existing window if Word is currently running on the PC. How do I force a fresh and independent instance of Word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `New Word.Application` is preferred if the project has a reference to the Word APIs. Based on the sample code in the question, that would be the case in this instance.

Another possibility would be to create a new `Process` and hook up to that. In this case, a reference to the Word APIs would not be necessary (late-binding).

```
    Dim wdApp As Word.Application = New Word.Application()
    Dim oDoc As Word.Document = wdApp.Documents.Add() 'or wdApp.Documents.Open(filepath)
```

`CreateObject` should not be using an existing window, only `GetObject` would do that. Assuming the assertion in the question cannot be confirmed (I've never seen it happen, in over thirty years), then `CreateObject` is also possible for starting a new instance of an Office application. This would also not require a reference to the Word APIs.

As to the topic of maintaining an independent instance of an Office application: You may also want to refer to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54326239/3077495).

Comment: Thanks for the edits Cindy but especially for your answer and the C# reference. It expressed perfectly the problem I was having.